# Coordinate calculation for popover view

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, storyboard

In my app a button is placed at bottom of view controller.while clicking that button i  need a popover view with a table view inside it displayed just above the button i placed.my problem is my popover view's starting position is at the top of my view controller.i need a small popover view just above that button.I use landscape mode  . .

```
  UIViewController *popoverContent=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 265,   100,  400 , 800)];
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
// popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mmf.png"]];


UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0,400,800) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
table.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(107.0/255.0) green: (164.0/255) blue:(183.0/255) alpha:1];
[table setDataSource:self];
[table setDelegate:self];
[table setRowHeight:80];
[popoverView addSubview:table];

popoverContent.view = popoverView;
// popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover =
//CGSizeMake(250, 665);


self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                          initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverView.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
[self.popoverController  presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake( 265,680,400,800)
                                         inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

I tried many values for the coordinates but its starting position is not where i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
    UIViewController *popoverContent=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
    UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0,   0,  400 , 400)];
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    // popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mmf.png"]];


    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0,400,400) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    table.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(107.0/255.0) green: (164.0/255) blue:(183.0/255) alpha:1];
    [table setRowHeight:80];
    [popoverView addSubview:table];

    popoverContent.view = popoverView;
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(popoverView.frame.size.width, popoverView.frame.size.width);

    UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                              initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    [popoverController  presentPopoverFromRect:btnLogin.frame
                                        inView:btnLogin.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

**NOTE**
You just make sure of the `frame of your button` and make sure to present from the `view that contains button`

Comment: I am getting an error"Property btnsection not found on object of type uitableview cell"

Comment: please look on the update btnLogin my button you can place your button here

Answer (score 1):

try with this one it'l help you,

```
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        UIView*   popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 320, 260)];
        popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0,320,260) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    table.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(107.0/255.0) green: (164.0/255) blue:(183.0/255) alpha:1];
    [table setDataSource:self];
    [table setDelegate:self];
    [table setRowHeight:80];
    [popoverView addSubview:table];
        popoverContent.view = popoverView;
        popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
        popoverRect = CGRectMake(100, 200, 1,30);

      //    in the above line change the position of the popover controller 

        popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 260);
        [popoverController 
         presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect
         inView:self.view
         permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
         animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea presenting popOver out of the blue. It's easier for the user when it is presented from a UI Control.

However try setting the contentPopOverSize in ViewDidLoad of the UIView & your TableView.

```
[self setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
```

The frame You give in CGRectMake should be relative to your button.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to suggest a proper coordinates?

Comment: No You can suggest the size of popover in the viewvontroller you are using for the popover.The x & y can be given in CGRECTMAKE of presentPopoverFromRect  of the UIPopOverViewController Method.

Comment: whatever values i am giving ,the view is starting from top of the iPad.only bottom position of the view is changing.i dont know why .

Answer (score 0):

**presentPopoverFromRect** is the rect where the popover will point to

```
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:yourBtn.frame inView:self.view    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

just keep in mind that yourBtn's frame is calculated wrt viewcontroller's view, if your button is inside any other view, then its coordinates will be calculated wrt that view and the positioning will not be correct.